# How do I grab a value of an item in a List of Tuples based off of a value from another item?

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I'm trying to grab a value of an item by looking at the value of another item within that same tuple within a list of tuples. What I ultimately need to do is grab all the Tuples that have a specific Item2, choose the most recent DateTime from that selection and grab Item1.

So for example, if I wanted to ultimately grab the most recent name from the "Programmer group, I would expect the logic to grab all the Item2s that say "Programmer", see which one has the most recent date and output "Stan" since 6/25 is more recent than 6/20.

```
    List<Tuple<string, string, DateTime>> myList;
    myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>("Bob", "Programmer", 6/20/2013));
    myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>("Stan", "Programmer", 6/25/2012));
    myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>("Curly", "Athlete", 6/20/2013));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly simple operation with LINQ. The first step is to order the list by DateTime (Item3), after that you can just chain `First()` on the query and it will return the most recent item. Note that LINQ operations are not done in place, meaning the order of itmes in `myList` will not be affected by this operation. It will create a new `IEnumerable` that is order by `tuple.Item3` then give you the first item from that.

```
Tuple<string, string, DateTime> mostRecent = myList.Orderby(x => x.Item3).First();
```

To add a restriction on group you simply need to add a where clause.

```
Tuple<string, string, DateTime> mostRecent = myList.Where(y => y.Item2 == "Programmer").Orderby(x => x.Item3).First();
```

I'd recommend checking out the docs on the LINQ to Objects query operators. Everything I've used is a standard query operator and you'll likely see them all over the place in modern C# code bases. If you understand how to use the standard query operators like Select, Where, OrderBy, ThenBy, and maybe Join and SelectMany you'll become far more proficient at operating on collections.

Comment: I see what you mean, but there are also situations where a DateTime from another group I'm not concerned with can be higher than the ones in he group I AM looking at. So wouldn't this code still sort by all of the DateTimes? (So if Curly's DateTime was something like 7/15/2013 instead, would that be before Bob and Stan's DateTimes?)

Comment: @Zldamstr you can modify this for whatever results you want. I'll add another query to get only items from the "Programmer" group.

Comment: Great! I just had to change it to OrderByDescending to fit my needs. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Tuple<string, string, DateTime>> myList = new List<Tuple<string,string,DateTime>>();

myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>("Bob", "Programmer", new DateTime(2013,6,20)));
myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>("Stan", "Programmer", new DateTime(2013, 6, 25)));
myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>("Curly", "Athlete", new DateTime(2013, 6, 20)));

var result = myList.Where(x => x.Item2.Equals("Programmer")).OrderByDescending(x => x.Item3).Take(1);
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand the portion after .Where, but could you explain why the the .AsEnumerable() is necessary?

Comment: In this case it is not necessary. Lately I've been working with DataTable objects and using AsEnumerable() because in this situation I need it in order to be able to perform LINQ operations over it, as you can see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx